# Rails: How to pass select_tag value to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with select_tag where I want to pass the value :id to my controller then I need to pass it to mailer, so no need to save it in the DB, I can't make it working ;( Cheers.

View

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "requests", :action => "sendpricelist") do %>
<%= select_tag 'pricelist', options_from_collection_for_select(Pricelist.all, :id, :name) %>
<%= submit_tag("Send pricelist")%>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def sendpricelist
@a = params[:pricelist] || []
@aa = "test"
SaasMailer.pricelist_request_email(@a, @aa).deliver_now
end
```

Route

```
resources :requests do
resources :updates
get '/sendpricelist/' => 'requests#sendpricelist', as: :sendpricelist
end
```

Output

Request Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Ps5qXEXhwaNNSreTC+Db2sJQ1MDfwrp3R18CyU0qp4iTUqdor6xoytNu+rKStGNhhy6tnHAUzosM0mHfbjGcKQ==",
 "pricelist"=>"1",
 "commit"=>"Send pricelist"}
```

Comment: You are doing fine, you are getting id in your params "pricelist"=>"1". What is the exact issue. Are you getting any error?

Comment: @AnujDhanju Thanks for getting back to me. The problem is that @a is nil     ;(

Comment: Have you tried like params["pricelist"]?

Comment: @AnujDhanju No I did Not tried yet. Thanks s lot for your help.

Comment: Ok try this one, If its work I will update as answer.

Comment: I will. Cheers.

Comment: @AnujDhanju Sadly, its not working :(